# Automatically watch all GitHub repos forked from my original

Tags: github

A lot of people are [forking my GitHub repo](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/network/members) and I would like to be able to see what new features they may be working on without having to manually visit each fork to watch.

How to automatically watch all of these repositories?  And can I set up all new forks be watched in the future?

Right now I have to watch them manually, it takes many clicks.

Comment: You mean you don't want to use the network graph? https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/network

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise: That's what I am doing now. But I would prefer being notified by RSS, rather than having to check manually every once in a while. The `https://github.com/nicolas-raoul.private.atom` RSS feed notifies me of any change to any repository marked as "watched".

Comment: Here may be https://help.github.com/articles/watching-repositories/ have a look or https://github.com/blog/1204-notifications-stars

Answer (score 1):

Just write a small script with [Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/). That should be fairly easy.

1. [Get the list of forks](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/)
2. [Foreach result set watching](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/watching/)

Comment: Cool solution ! The second link was broken. Because I didn't got the point, I searched for API repo watching and edited your post. Hope this is ok for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Was looking around for a solution to this problem. Didn't see one, so used the [previous answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/30370/259184) and threw [this shell script](https://github.com/altsalt/gh-fork-autowatch) together.

The gist is that you enter your `username`, `authentication token`, and `list of repositories to exclude`. The script then makes three API calls to [fetch your repos](https://docs.github.com/v3/repos/#list-repositories-for-a-user), [fetch the forks of each repo](https://docs.github.com/v3/repos/forks/), and [set a watch on each of these forks](https://docs.github.com/v3/activity/watching/).

You may want to add it as a cronjob to regularly check for and follow new forks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134896)

Comment: Gotcha, updated the post, thanks for the feedback!